# After connecting to Azure SSO, when testing the API in the publisher UI, the API call does not work

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I still haven't been able to solve this problem..
when I call the API from "Tryout" in Publisher, it comes out like the error message below. No matter how much I regenerate the key, it keeps saying that it is not valid.

Please help me on this.

Command

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://xxxxx:8243/systemname/1.0.0/AMTSrestapi/api/getdoclist' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Internal-Key: eyJraWQiOiJnYXRld2F5X2NlcnRpZmljYXRlX2FsaWFzIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiI0ODM3MDlAY2FyYm9uLnN1cGVyIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3Nnc2RpYXBpbDAwMS5zZWFnYXRlLmNvbTo5NDQzXC9vYXV0aDJcL3Rva2VuIiwia2V5dHlwZSI6IlBST0RVQ1RJT04iLCJzdWJzY3JpYmVkQVBJcyI6W3sic3Vic2NyaWJlclRlbmFudERvbWFpbiI6bnVsbCwibmFtZSI6IkdBTVRTIiwiY29udGV4dCI6IlwvZ21hdHNcLzEuMC4wIiwicHVibGlzaGVyIjoiNDgzNzA5IiwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMC4wIiwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uVGllciI6bnVsbH1dLCJleHAiOjE2MzM3MzI3MjgsInRva2VuX3R5cGUiOiJJbnRlcm5hbEtleSIsImlhdCI6MTYzMzY3MjcyOCwianRpIjoiNDg2YmY4MmItYTMyYi00ZWQ1LTk4NDItNmE4ODU5OTZkZWU4In0.n_DPcyZ7DfPwc_nQTbSB6buHQnacAHGAWsIqVE0UvezrFjF5wu9mQ0UGPO8rBzN_uABoEpscR1PxI5A0LLicP566_H61hwl2hy4dUvYhZwVrCLVneBCxlmO4o9b3d1nJcOcsBf9zAmUDn3_M0K-yBxVrXYZuiA3FFRBK0YyzZQAmhmUatVvh_D7gTXVHR2STYeaRYPqSalbxxyaWLCzhD2sY66BdSD2q476dmXGhYMYTRuMFZrqiALcdhlZpdjAlTHJz0G7q6rCv5EHzuUnGRpBvNaYzzQPjYmHYIBf7RKfXjHMXlHQIp7KCdi9WbrLIUYvQ-Tj5a5v8BVv1d8wW6Q'
```

Error message.

```
{
  "code": "900901",
  "message": "Invalid Credentials",
  "description": "Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
}
```

wso2carbon.log

```
Log file [2021-10-06 13:50:07,068] ERROR - InternalAPIKeyAuthenticator Invalid Internal Key.XXXXXUlMyNTYifQ [2021-10-06 13:50:07,069] WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHbWF.png

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238199/discussion-on-question-by-seeandsea-after-connecting-to-azure-sso-when-testing).

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned error can occur when the API Manager was not able to validate or verify the Signature of the Internal Key access token.

##### Explanation

The API Manager generates the Internal Key access token (a JWT Token) and signs it with the private key of the Primary Keystore (which is configured under `keystore.primary` with alias).

During the validation process, the API Manager searches for the public cert of the specific private key using the alias `gateway_certificate_alias` (this can be configured as well from the TOML).

Hence, if the default shipped Keystore is changed or replaced and the Primary Keystore configurations are updated in the TOML, then it is also required to export and import the public certificate of the relevant private key with the alias `gateway_certificate_alias` to the `client-truststore.jks`.

##### Recovery Steps

**Go through the question comments to understand the steps and shared information*

As per the shared information, you have generated a new Keystore with an existing cert for the SSL communication and have replaced the `wso2carbon.jks` as well as configured the new keystore in the TOML configurations. Therefore, it is required to update the public certs in the `client-truststore` with relevant credentials.

Follow the given steps to update the cert that has been aliased as `gateway_certificate_alias` in the `client-truststore.jks`

1. Export the public cert of your new Keystore (enter the Keystore password when prompted)

   ```sh
   keytool -export -alias apimanagercert7 -file wso2.crt -keystore newkeystore7.jks
   ```
2. Import the public cert to the client-truststore with the alias `gateway_certificate_alias` (enter the Truststore password when prompted)

   ```sh
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias gateway_certificate_alias -file wso2.crt
   ```

If you get any errors when trying to import the certs to the truststore mentioning the alias exists, then execute the following command to delete the alias and perform the above-given steps again to import it

```sh
keytool -delete -alias gateway_certificate_alias -keystore client-truststore.jks
```

After performing the steps, restart the API Manager server and try invoking the API using the Internal Key from the Publisher portal.

Comment: Appriciate for your help